# Инициализация REST сервиса

Tags: java, tomcat, rest

Всем доброго времени суток

[Я по примеру](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150176/) сделал свой REST сервис, только на Tomcat

Но у меня появилась проблема, мне необходимо по заданию, при запуске сервера отправлять некие данные на главный сервер.

Но я не знаю где и как это все прикрутить, я новичок в этом всем, и тут нету кода -

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
```

где бы можно было это сделать эту инициализацию. 
спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создай класс, который имплементирует интерфейс `ServletContextListener`.
И напиши что требуется в методе `contextInitialized`, в `contextDestroyed` может оставить пустым если не нужен.
Потом этот класс пропиши в `web.xml` в слушателях:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>mypackage.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш ответ очень помог мне.